# Exclude blank CELLS in =FILTER() but keeping the rest in the row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have only seen how to remove the entire row if you get a single blank cell but I basically just want to slide the cells to the right over:

Original:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Data | Data1 |  |  |
| 2 | Data |  | Data2 |  |
| 3 | Bad Data | Data3 |  |  |
| 4 | Data |  | Data4 |  |
| 5 | Data |  |  | Data5 |

Result trying to get after filter:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Data | Data1 |  |  |
| 2 | Data | Data2 |  |  |
| 3 | Data | Data4 |  |  |
| 4 | Data | Data5 |  |  |

I know this is odd since normally this would mean things would be messy but columns B, C, and D are mutually exclusive so they will never both have a value. I'm also trying to accomplish this by using functions and not clicking buttons in the tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With LET and BYROW:

```
=LET(
    grp,A1:A5,
    dta,BYROW(B1:D5,LAMBDA(a,INDEX(a,MATCH("*",a,0)))),
    FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2},grp,dta),grp<>"Bad Data"))
```

The BYROW part goes row by row of the data and returns the first cell with data in each row as an array.

Then it is just a matter of using CHOOSE() to stack the two arrays side by side and filter bases on the criteria.

[image]

There is currently a function in Beta called HSTACK that can replace the CHOOSE when it is release to the whole.

```
=LET(
    grp,A1:A5,
    dta,BYROW(B1:D5,LAMBDA(a,INDEX(a,MATCH("*",a,0)))),
    FILTER(HSTACK(grp,dta),grp<>"Bad Data"))
```

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you. Is it possible to use a similar solution if there were 2 cells next to each other with data per row? Still following the mutual exclusive property mentioned above. Thanks!